# How to write output as fixed width file from spark to hdfs?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I have to read a csv file from hdfs, then I need to apply the logic that every column is padded to a fixed width then I need store back to hdfs as fixed width file only. Not in any other form example csv or parquet.

If I read a input from hdfs as csv that look like below example:

```
Name, age, phonenumber
A, 25,9900999999
B, 26,7654890234
C, 27,5643217897
```

Then I need apply logic on each column with fixed width like first column width should set as 15, 2nd column 3, 3rd as 10

Output should look like this in hdfs.

```
Name      age   phonenumber           
A         25    9900999999
B         26    7654890234
C         27    5643217897
```

Then that fixed width data I need to write it to hdfs as fixed width file format.

Answer (score 0):

your sample output seems to have a separator since there are spaces between age and phonenumber. I'd guess this is a tab separator in which case you can read the csv and save it back with a `spark.save.option("sep","\t").csv("filename")`

but if what you wrote is correct you can get it with:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rpad
val df=spark.read.option("header","false").csv("...")
val out= df.select(rpad($"_c0",15," "),
                   rpad($"_c1",3," "),
                   rpad($"_c2",10," "))                   
out.map(_.mkString("")).write.text("filename")
```

note that I set the header to false so that they'd also be padded

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast all columns as string, if inferSchema is already used.
Map the length to the df.columns, so that you can handle this dynamically.
Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq(("A", 25,9900999999L),("B", 26,7654890234L),("C", 27,5643217897L)).toDF("Name","age","phonenumber")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Name: string, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+----+---+-----------+
|Name|age|phonenumber|
+----+---+-----------+
|A   |25 |9900999999 |
|B   |26 |7654890234 |
|C   |27 |5643217897 |
+----+---+-----------+


scala> val widths = Array(5,3,10)
widths: Array[Int] = Array(5, 3, 10)

scala> df.columns.zip(widths)
res235: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Name,5), (age,3), (phonenumber,10))

scala> df.columns.zip(widths).foldLeft(df){ (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x._1,rpad( trim(col(x._1).cast("string")),x._2," ")) }.show(false)
+-----+---+-----------+
|Name |age|phonenumber|
+-----+---+-----------+
|A    |25 |9900999999 |
|B    |26 |7654890234 |
|C    |27 |5643217897 |
+-----+---+-----------+
```

To verify the padding..

```
scala> df.columns.zip(widths).foldLeft(df){ (acc,x) => acc.withColumn(x._1,rpad( trim(col(x._1).cast("string")),x._2,"-")) }.show(false)
+-----+---+-----------+
|Name |age|phonenumber|
+-----+---+-----------+
|A----|25-|9900999999 |
|B----|26-|7654890234 |
|C----|27-|5643217897 |
+-----+---+-----------+


scala>
```

Comment: i have one more issue is that now in hdfs data looking like below                                                                                                          Name age phonenumber
akshatha 27 9900090252
amrutha 28 9900902423
sharath 29 9900902878

Comment: write the dataframe as a csv file and you will get the newlines for each record.

Comment: i want my output should look like below with proper alignment  in hdfs please help                                                                                                                 Name         age      phonenumber
akshatha        27  9900090252
amrutha         28  9900902423
sharath         29  9900902878
akshatha suresh 28  9535811138

Comment: Stack overflow has removed all the formatting.. pls update in the question section itseld