# How to convert dataframe to a text file in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I unloaded snowflake table and created a data frame.
this table has data of various datatype.
I tried to save it as a text file but got an error:

> Text data source does not support Decimal(10,0).

So to resolve the error, I casted my select query and converted all columns to string datatype.

Then I got the below error:

> Text data source supports only single column, and you have 5 columns.

my requirement is to create a text file as follows.

```
"column1value column2value column3value and so on"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSV output with a space delimiter:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select([F.col(c).cast('string') for c in df.columns]).write.csv('output', sep=' ')
```

If you want only 1 output file, you can add `.coalesce(1)` before `.write`.

Comment: i have tried csv file and it works. But my requirement is a text file.

Comment: @FlashBang a CSV file is the same as a text file if you use a space delimiter

Comment: hi @mck , it totally worked and I was able to change delimiters as well. I have another query to ask. suppose my column 1 has variable length data like "abcd" in first row and 'abcdefg' in second row, I want to limit the characters. for example if I could set 10 characters for first column then first row value sould be "abcd<6 spaces>" and second row value should be "abcdefg<4 spaces>" . I mean how can I have blank spaces?

Comment: @FlashBang you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54362054/how-to-write-output-as-fixed-width-file-from-spark-to-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one column if you want to write using `spark.write.text`. You can use csv instead as suggested in @mck's answer or you can concatenate all columns into one before you write:

```scala
df.select(
  concat_ws(" ", df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast("string")): _*).as("value")
).write
  .text("output")
```